# Button not creating a file and showing email provider option menu when pressed

Tags: java, android, email

I've created a button that creates a file then sends it as an attachment to an email,
it grabs the text from one of the textviews, saves it to a .txt and sends it. A small email service option selector should show up too. The code is meant to create a file path if one is not already there. This code is above the onCreate method and in a regular activity.
i keep getting this in the logcat (specific message marked by (-->)):

```
-->08-06 12:53:01.019  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)<---
08-06 12:53:01.019  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
08-06 12:53:01.019  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.Locator.clickedUpdate(Locator.java:76)
08-06 12:53:01.019  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:53:01.019  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3860)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
08-06 12:53:01.029  18432-18432/com.example.adrian.trucktracker W/System.err﹕ ... 15 more
```

My code:

```
    public void clickedUpdate(View view)
        {
            TextView dLong = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textLong);
            TextView dLat = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textLat);
            String dataLat = dLat.getText().toString();
            String dataLong = dLong.getText().toString();
            boolean UpdateResume;
            if(!(dataLat.equals("") && !(dataLong.equals(""))))
            {
                UpdateResume = true;
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateResume = false;
            }
            TelephonyManager telephonemanager =(TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String PhoneNumber = telephonemanager.getLine1Number();
            File DataDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"/LocationData");
            if(!DataDir.exists())
            {
                try
                {
                    DataDir.mkdir();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            File Data = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"data" + File.separator+"Locationer.txt");
            String datapath = Data + ""
            if(!Data.exists())
            {
                try {
line 76 ---->    Data.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (UpdateResume = true)
                {
    if (Data.exists())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(Data);
                            BufferedWriter bfWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                            bfWriter.write(PhoneNumber + "," + dataLat + "," + dataLong);
                            bfWriter.close();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            Intent emailintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailintent.setType("text/plain");
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"apraiswater@legion-logistics.com"});
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Data");
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World!");
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String DataAttachment = "Android/data/Locationer.txt";
            File filer = new File(root, DataAttachment);
            if (!filer.exists() || filer.canRead())
            {
                return;
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filer);
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent, "Choose an Email provider"));
    }
```

Comment: its already there, its the entire button code; the logcat didnt specify which line

Comment: i've added in an indication of line 76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few details seem relevant:

First you check the existence of the dir:

```
        File DataDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"/LocationData");
        if(!DataDir.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                DataDir.mkdir();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir()), your `try{}catch(Exception e){}` aren't needed. You just would need to check whether the directory actually exists. There's the additional problem that you seem to create a subdirectory of another subdirectory. So, you might want to exchange it to [`mkdirs()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) instead.

Afterwards, you try to create the File if it doesn't exist

```
   try {
line 76 ---->    Data.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Take a look at the documentation for [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()). You might note that it tells you

> This method is not generally useful. For creating temporary files, use
>   createTempFile(String, String) instead. For reading/writing files, use
>   FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, or RandomAccessFile, all of which
>   can create files.

but maybe, if you've included the proper permissions, the changes I suggested above will help to make your code work.

Comment: I've decided to do what you said and just avoid doing it that way, inseatd im using a fileoutput stream and I no longer get the error